# Can I install the drivers offered by HP on my Laptop using Wine?

Tags: drivers, wine, windows-7, proprietary

I am asking this question because the drivers provided on the HP website will cost me around 1.2 GB of bandwidth download.

Before downloading them I wanted to confirm if it's possible to install the drivers provided by HP because they are for MS Windows.

Comment: Not recommended to do so!

Comment: Care to tell us why you think you need to download drivers from the HP website. Mind you: this is NOT windows. Linux uses generic drivers.

Comment: @Ankit Is this for a printer? Wireless connection? You have not specified?

Comment: nope, drivers for my mice, graphics, bios etc.

Comment: Oh. Well then, are any of these things not functioning properly?

Comment: i want to update my BIOS drivers. Laptop shipped with f.42 and now HP offers f.63.

Comment: Read up on what you need to do to update your BIOS; most times you download a file and execute it or upload it from your BIOS. Has not alot to do with using Ubuntu or Windows or Mac OS. And if your BIOS does not cause you any problems I would leave it alone.

Comment: alright, thanks for the information. I was gathering information for my knowledge. :)

Comment: ofcourse :D thats what au is for :D and we all are more than willing to dump all our knowledge on your lap :+ @ankit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Besides that... I have 3 HP printers here and not one of them needs special drivers from the HP website. The newest of those 3 is a HP PSC 2170. Printer, scanner and cardreader work out of the box.

Printers work through a generic piece of software called [CUPS](http://www.cups.org/).

> CUPS is the standards-based, open source printing system developed by Apple Inc. for Mac OS® X and other UNIX®-like operating systems

You can add printers from `dash` by searching for `printers`. It will show this:

[image]

You can add printers manually here ...

[image]

but after plugging my printer in it gets automatically detected:

[image]

The same goes for your mouse, keyboard. Graphics you can install an extra driver for via `dash`, `additional hardware` but this is also a native driver (ie. "built by ubuntu for ubuntu"). BIOS is not OS related so I will leave that one out ;)

The only thing I do know that benefits from a windows driver (but that was 3 releases ago) is your wireless card and only if it is a Microsoft based wireless. But I think that those days are behind us.

Comment: And I would appreciate feedback from the person giving me a downvote.